# How can i get the normal Url from reddit using python praw

Tags: python, praw

My problem is that reddit gives my a a coded url instead of the normal one. The problem I am trying to solve is that i need to get the normal url from the certain reddit post, not the one my code gives me.

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="",
    client_secret="",
    password="",
    user_agent="",
    username="",
)
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("perfectlycutscreams")

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    print(submission.url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the permalink attribute, and add `https://reddit.com` to the front:

```py
import praw

REDDIT_URL = "https://reddit.com"

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="",
    client_secret="",
    password="",
    user_agent="",
    username="",
)
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("perfectlycutscreams")

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    print(REDDIT_URL + submission.permalink)
```